# How nested can rbac roles be in azure? Specifically a storage account using ADLS GEN2 storage containers?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

So in Azure Active Directory when I was adding a group to "Users and Groups" in the Enterprise application and noticed it was warning that it only works with users directly in the group and would not cascade permissions like if a group was added and that group had a group and that group had users they would not get the permissions. Only the users in the direct group that was added.

So this got me wondering if this applies to rbac permissions in items like Azure Storage accounts like ADLS GEN2 storage containers by going to the container > Access Control (IAM) > Role Assignments then adding a group to a lets says "Storage Blob Data Contributor". Then that group has a bunch of users but also has other groups added to it that then have users. I know the users directly in the group will get permissions but will the users in the group thats nested in the 1st group also get these permissions?

Was not sure if these permissions behave the same as I saw in enterprise applications or if they behave differently (support nesting)? When I went to add I saw no warnings so was not sure about this.

If no one knows I'll just have to get an account setup with no permissions and try adding it to a group then try and then remove from group then add to a nested group and try and see what happens. And if it works try 2-4 levels deep and see what happens.

[Azure Warning when adding a group to "Users and Groups" of an Enterprise Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdXlA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you see the notification, when you assign a group to application, only users in the group will have access. the assignment does not cascade to nested groups.

Group-based assignment requires azure ad premium P1 or P2. and group based assignment is supported for security groups only, Nested Group memberships and Microsoft 365 groups are not currently supported.

coming to RBAC, Role assignments are transitive for groups which means that if a user is a member of a group and that group is member of another group that has a role assignment, the user will have the permissions in the role assignment.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/assign-user-or-group-access-portal)